# In a custom Windows Mobile Control, what is the correct XMTA to handle codegen/serialization of null images for properties?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm building a Windows Mobile Compact Frameworks custom control that has optional images as properties.  Normally I don't bother with design time support, in this case I need to make that available.  If an optional image is not present and the designer attempts to update the code, Visual Studio throws an exception

"Code generation for property "MyImage" failed.  Error was: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'"

I have an XMTA file and have tried different combinations including different values for "DesignerSerializationVisibility".  Either the code behind for the property doesn't get generated or an exception is thrown if the optional image is not present.  If the image is present, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked at the Smart Device Framework, and this is what we're doing in the XMTA:

```
<Property Name="ActiveBackgroundImage">
    <Category>Appearance</Category>
    <DefaultValue>
        <Type>System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Type>
    </DefaultValue>
    <Description>The background image displayed for the control in an active state.</Description>
</Property>
```

Note the lack of a `<Value>` element under `<DefaultValue>`.  I presume leaving it out sets the default to `null`;

Comment: Fix what issue?  The above is a working example of setting a default image for a custom control via the control's XMTA.

Comment: Issue with WinForm with OpenNETCF.Button2: Code generation for property 'BackgroundImage' failed.  Error was: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'